# Expected commajson(514) while creating a test server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, typescript

package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "http-server": "^14.1.1"
  }
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server -p 8436"
  }
}
```

With this message below: The 'scripts' member is an object hash of script commands that are run at various times in the lifecycle of your package. The key is the lifecycle event, and the value is the command to run at that point.

> Expected comma json(514)

The error is marked in the " : " signs after typing "scripts" and I do not understand the error.

Comment: You're missing a comma after the `"dependencies"` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a comma after your dependencies, so your "package.json" should look like this

```
{
   "dependencies": { "http-server": "^14.1.1" },
   "scripts": { "start": "http-server -p 8436" }
}
```

and not like this

```
{
   "dependencies": { "http-server": "^14.1.1" }
   "scripts": { "start": "http-server -p 8436" }
}
```